# Can't create new geodatabase for SQLServer Express in ArcCatalog 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, sql-server, arccatalog

I'm trying to create a new geodatabase in my local SQLExpress Database Server from ArcCatalog 10.0 (ArcInfo). I can create a database server entry just fine (image below):

[image]

[ESRI documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000070000000) has me convinced that at this stage, I should be able to right-click on that server entry, and select the "Create Geodatabase" option.  There is no such option:

[image]

It seems a bit like [this ArcDesktop 10.0 bug](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37983), but following the workaround instructions saw no joy for me.  Any ideas on where I can go from here in solving this?

Comment: Do you have permission on the server to do this? you will need create, view & modify permissions for the credentials you're using.

Comment: The SQLServer instance runs on on my local machine. I am an administrator for the machine.  Running ArcCatalog as administrator does not result in the missing "Create Geodatabase" popup-menu item appearing.

Comment: Local admin does not mean DB admin automatically; I.T. can have admin privileges to a server but still not be able to modify the database unless they're given permissions in the database. Do you need to enter credentials to connect? and was the SQL express version installed from your ArcGis install discs or did you have it there already?

Comment: The SQLExpress Server database was set up for me as part of the ArcGIS install.  It's possible that this was not done as per the ArcGIS instructions, which might be where my problem is. If they didn't set me up as an administration user, I'm guessing this might be the end result. That's given me a new avenue to look into thanks Michael.

Comment: I found instructions for re-starting the SQLServer Express database single-user, and [injecting administration credentials](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11143/how-to-access-a-newly-installed-sql-server-2008-r2-instance-if-you-do-not-know-the-login-and-passwor.aspx), which I've now done.  No joy, unfortunately.

Comment: can you remove and reinstall SQLServer? It's possible that some extra files are required that aren't in the standard install. Also on the desktop side, there may be client files needed like the ones that users must install to access PostgreSQL. I was under the impression that all the SDE personal client files are installed when SDE personal is installed from the disk.

Comment: I reinstalled SQLServer Express using the [original install media](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Installing_SQL_Server_Express/003n0000004t000000/)..

Right-clicking on the database server now gives me the "Add Geodatabase" option I was expecting.  It fails stating ""Error creating this geodatabase No ArcSDE server licence found" until I run [the patch utility](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37983) for the ESRI bug I mentioned above. 

Once I run the patcher, the creating of a new geodatabase works. Thanks for the ideas Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was solved by:

1) Completely Uninstalling the existing local SQLServer Express Server,

2) Reinstalling SQLServer Express from the ArcDesktop 10.0 install media, following the ESRI-supplied [install instructions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Installing_SQL_Server_Express/003n0000004t000000/), then

3) Running the [ESRI-supplied patch](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37983) utility for the known issue between ArcDesktop 10.0 and SQLServer Express around the error message "No ArcSDE Server License Found".

Huge props to [Michaeel Miles-Stimson](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37983) for the avenues to investigate.